# JSON to ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I read data from a URL http://copy-cat.at/api/index.json in JSON format.

My actual project is to fetch the JSON and parse it.

The Problem is now how I can create a listView with there multiple data and Display that?

mainactivity.java

```
package at.copy_cat.app.rest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            new HttpRequestTask().execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */



    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Greeting> {
        @Override
        protected Greeting doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "http://copy-cat.at/api/index.json";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());



                /**Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting[].class);**/
              Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting.class);

              /**  Greeting greeting = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting[].class));**/

               /** Greeting[] greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting[].class);
                Arrays.asList(greeting);**/


                return greeting;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return null;
        }



        Object result;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Greeting greeting) {





            TextView greetingIdText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_value);
            TextView greetingContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_value);
            //TextView greetingProductId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_id_value);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            //Hier ist der ganze String als Output vorhanden!
            //TODO PARSEN UND AUSGEBEN!

           String content = greeting.getContent();
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.label);
            Object b = listView.getAdapter();
            Log.e("TEST23243235Main",b.toString());





            try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(content);
                final int numberOfItemsInResp =json.length();


                processFinish(json.toString());

                //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               // bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
               // PlaceholderFragment fragobj = new PlaceholderFragment();
             //   fragobj.setArguments(bundle);





                for (int o = 0; o < numberOfItemsInResp; o++) {
                    JSONObject a = json.getJSONObject(o);
                    Log.e("TEST23243235", a.getString("id"));
                    //TextView greetingProductId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_value);
                    //((TextView) greetingProductId.findViewById(R.id.id_value)).setText(
                            a.getString("id");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("TEST23243235", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.

            }



            //greetingIdText.setText(greeting.getId());
            greetingContentText.setText(greeting.getContent());
            //greetingProductId.setText(greeting.getProductId());
        }



    }

    void processFinish(String output){
        Log.e("TEST23243235Finish",output);
         String out = output;

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        ListView list;
        //@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            // View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_main, container, false);
            //listview=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            //GridView gvproduct=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvproduct);
            //List<String> li=new ArrayList<>();
            //ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,li);
            //dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.label);
            // String content = greeting.getContent();

             //Log.v("TEST23243235YEEEE", result);

          //  String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");

           // Log.e("TEST23243235EDITTEXTL",strtext);

            ListView phoneListView =((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.label));



            ArrayList<String> phNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            phNumbers.add("4343534343");
            phNumbers.add("6767566766");

           // String content = greeting.getContent();
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, phNumbers);
            // Set The Adapter
            phoneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Greeting.java

```
package at.copy_cat.app.rest;

import android.util.Log;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 17.10.2017.
 */



@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

public class Greeting {




    // getters and setters

    public  List products;

        String convertedToString = "" + products;
        /**String[] value_split = convertedToString.split(",");**/
        String[] value_split = convertedToString.split("\\,");

    public String myMethod() {


        try {

           // Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJ1" + products);
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(products);
            //Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJ1" + products);


            String productList = "";
            for (int i = 0, len = json.length(); i < len; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject objects = json.optJSONObject(i);

                final int numberOfItemsInResp =json.length();
                ArrayList<String> demandesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(products);

                for (int o = 0; o < numberOfItemsInResp; o++){
                    JSONObject a = json.getJSONObject(o);
                   // Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJRRRR" + o);
                    //Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJRRRR" + a);

                    String images = a.getString("images");


                    //Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJimage" + first);


                   demandesList.add("{\"id\": \""+a.getString("id")+"\", \"title\": \""+a.getString("title")+"\",\"permalink\": \""+a.getString("permalink")+"\", \"status\": \"" + a.getString("status") + "\",\"regular_price\": \"" + a.getString("regular_price") + "\",\"price\": \"" + a.getString("price") + "\",\"description\": \"" + a.getString("description") + "\"}");



                   // Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJRMAP" + map);


                }

                return demandesList.toString();

            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("TEST23243235", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.

        }
        return "Placeholder";
    }

        public String getContent(){

            return myMethod();

        }


        public void setProducts(List products){

            this.products = products;
        }
        public class Model {
            private String title;
            private String id;
            private String idd;
            //other fields

            //getters and setters
        }





    public String getId() {
        return "1";
    }
    public String getProductId() {
        return "1";
    }
   /** public String getContent() {
     return this.convertedToString;

    }**/

}
```

The Situation now is I can read and parse the data but how can I display them in a listView?

Many Many Thanks - these are my first steps and now I'm stuck.....

Please ignore the "test log lines"...

Comment: google it, it's available directly visit the following site https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html

Comment: Ok thanks i will look @home . I tried it many times but the result was not that that i mean...

Comment: What kind of result do you want?

Comment: Shop Main Page also 2 Products per line 20 per Site you know what i mean?

Comment: Do you want to display the JSON data in the form of a list view?

Comment: Yes, is this the best way to display products on a page?

Comment: Many thank it worked now :)